# Azure Function V3 configuration with DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I have a Azure Function with 2 triggers:
[image]

I’m registering IService in my Startup like so:
[image]

I need a different configuration in the Service class depending on which trigger that is calling DoWork()? How can I achieve this using DI?

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public Service(/*Configuration to be injected depends on calling trigger */)
    { }
 
    public void DoWork()
    { }
}
```

Configuration extract:
[image]

[image]

Comment: That configuration would need to be passed into the `DoWork` member based on where it is being invoked. `public void DoWork(/*Configuration to be injected depends on calling trigger */)`

Comment: I'm aware of that. Atm I have this code in the Function1 execution body:
var config = new Config();
this.configuration.GetSection("Function1").Bind(config);
this.service.DoWork(config);
And similarly in Function2. However, I was wondering if this was achievable through DI.

Comment: Could you please refer this MS DOC:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#registering-services

Comment: @ErshadNozari - Refer to [this](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/blob/master/CleanArchitecture.Core/Implementation/ToDoItemsService.cs) repository which contains the example what you require.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou [user1672994](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672994/user1672994). Posting your suggestion as an answer so that it will be helpful for other community members who face similar kind of issues.

Below is the example code to implement todo work items where this will be helpful in resolving your issue.

```
using AZV3CleanArchitecture.Models;
using AZV3CleanArchitecture.Options;
using AZV3CleanArchitecture.Providers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AZV3CleanArchitecture.Services
{
    public class ToDoItemsService : IToDoItemsService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        private readonly ToDoItemsServiceOptions toDoItemsServiceOptions;
        private readonly ILogger<ToDoItemsService> logger;

        public ToDoItemsService(HttpClient httpClient, IOptions<ToDoItemsServiceOptions> toDoItemsServiceOptions, ILogger<ToDoItemsService> logger)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
            this.toDoItemsServiceOptions = toDoItemsServiceOptions.Value;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<ToDoItem> GetToDoItem(int id)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Retrieving item: {{{Constants.TodoItemId}}}", id);

            var getUrl = $"{this.toDoItemsServiceOptions.BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/')}/todos/{id}";
            using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, getUrl))
            {
                using (var response = await this.httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage))
                {
                    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    logger.LogWarning($"Retrieved item: {{{Constants.TodoItemId}}}. Logged as warning for demo.", id);
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ToDoItem>(responseString);
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<ToDoItem>> GetAllToDoItems(int id)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Retrieving all todo items");
            var getUrl = $"{this.toDoItemsServiceOptions.BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/')}/todos";
            using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, getUrl))
            {
                using (var response = await this.httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage))
                {
                    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ToDoItem>>(responseString);
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task<ToDoItem> CreateToDoItem(ToDoItem toDoItem)
        {
            // call service and return the output

            return await Task.FromResult(new ToDoItem() { Id = 1, UserId = 1, Title = "Some Dummy Title", Completed = true });
        }

        public Task<ToDoItem> UpdateToDoItem(ToDoItem toDoItem)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

for further information check the [ToDoItemServices](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/blob/master/CleanArchitecture.Core/Implementation/ToDoItemsService.cs) link.